# Second derivative test for $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ and $f''(0)=2$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f\in C(\mathbb{R}^1)$ with $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ and $f''(0)=2$. Prove that $0$ is strict local minima of $f$.

**Proof:** Since $f''(0)=2$ then $\exists\delta>0$ such that for any $t\in \mathbb{R}^1$ with $0<|t|<\delta$ we have $\left|\frac{f'(t)}{t}-2\right|<1 \Leftrightarrow$ $1<\frac{f'(t)}{t}<3$.

For $t\in(0,\delta)$ we have $f'(t)>t>0$ then $f'(t)>0$ and for $t\in(-\delta,0)$ we have $f'(t)<t<0$ then $f'(t)<0$. Hence $f$ strictly increases on $(0,\delta)$ and strictly decreases on $(-\delta,0)$ with $f(0)=0$. Hence $0$ is strict local minima of $f$.

I am sorry if this topic is repeated since this is famous result but I have never seen it's proof.

Can anyone check my proof please?

Comment: The proof seems completely OK to me but ... well, I don't consider myself an expert. I don't see any flaws. The function $x^2$ is such a function.

Comment: I think you may try to generalize this statement by taking some constant $C > 0$ instead of $2$. Then think also what happens when $C < 0$. At least I would try these just as exercises.

Comment: @peter.petrov, It seems interesting problem. I will solve it soon. When I solve can you check it please?

Comment: OK, I will try.